# Laravel, applying where after with in Eloquent syntax

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get all questions, by category, where the author of the question is `Y`.

This is how I am trying to do so:

```
QuestionCategory::with('questions')->where('questions.source', '=', $userId)->get();
```

The problem is that, it does not apply the where to `questions` table, but to `question_categories` one.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'questions.source' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `question_categories` where
>   `questions`.`source` = 2)

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Read the docs, tbh. The eloquent page has all the information you need for exactly this. Make sure you define the relationships on your models, and add a closure to extend the query for the relationship, as stated in some of the examples below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions table is eager loaded in a separate query, so your where statement doesn't have access to the questions table.

You'll have to join it in order to query it.

```
QuestionCategory::with('questions')
    ->join('questions', 'question_id', '=', 'questions.id')
    ->where('questions.source', '=', $userId)
    ->get();
```

Comment: but... why the `->join('questions', 'question_id', '=', 'questions.id')` ? I don't get that

Comment: Yeah, it does seem a bit clumsy. But how the eager loading works, it will load query "SELECT * FROM question_categories", then it will run a separate query "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id IN (.., ..,)" for every ID that the previous statement returned.

So essentially, your original query is "SELECT * FROM question_categories WHERE questions.source = $userId".

The join is not ideal, but currently I don't think there's a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to limit based on a relationship, you will have to structure your code a bit differently.  This should work for you...

```
QuestionCategory::with(array('questions' => function($q) use ($userID)
{
    $q->where('source', '=', $userID);
}))->get();
```

Please note though that this does not limit the `QuestionCategory` as they will all still be grabbed.  If a `QuestionCategory` doesn't have a source with that user id associated with it, it will still grab that `QuestionCategory`.

If you want only QuestionCategories that have a source with that user id, you may use the `whereHas()` function.

```
$categories = QuestionCategory::whereHas('permissions', function($q)
{
    $q->where('name', '=', 'CreateUser');

})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you should see the relationship system of laravel.
In your model you can specify a relation between two tables.

```
Class User Extends Eloquent {
    public function questions()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('Your Model Question name', 'userid column name in questions table', 'userid column name in users table')
    }    
}
```

Then to access to that relation

```
$user = User::find('tape an userid');
$questionsByUser = $user->questions;
```

I'm not sure that's what you ask but that's gonna give you an instance with all questions owned by an user.